# Regex is not matching even though match exact value in bash

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sh

```
echo "Hello World";
string="v13.2.exe"
pattern='^v[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.exe$'

if  [[ $str =~ pattern ]]; then
    echo "found"
else
    echo "not found"
fi
```

it always print not found. what is wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In one case (`$str`) you are not using the variable you have defined (`$string`). In the other (`pattern`), you're missing the `$` sign (`$pattern`). Try

```sh
string="v13.2.exe"
pattern='^v[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.exe$'

if  [[ $string =~ $pattern ]]; then
    echo "found"
else
    echo "not found"
fi
```

```
found
```